# Wrong kind in `symbolVal` to get a type-level string at runtime

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I'm trying to understand how to work with type-level strings in Haskell. I have a data type declared as follows:

```
data MyType (s :: Symbol) t = MyType t
```

Think of it as a value of type `t` tagged in some way.

Now, when trying to use `symbolVal`, I get an error that I don't understand. Consider this code:

```
func :: KnownSymbol s => MyType s t -> String
func _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

The code triggers the following compile error:

```
file.hs:63:21: error:
    • Couldn't match kind ‘*’ with ‘Symbol’
      When matching types
        proxy0 :: Symbol -> *
        Proxy :: * -> *
      Expected type: proxy0 n0
        Actual type: Proxy s0
    • In the first argument of ‘symbolVal’, namely ‘(Proxy :: Proxy s)’
      In the expression: symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
      In an equation for ‘func’: func _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
   |
63 | func _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
   |
```

I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong here. If I write `Proxy "hello"` instead of `Proxy s` the code compiles and the function actually returns "hello", so at least it seems that I'm getting *something* right.

So how do I get back a runtime representation of the type-level Symbol?

Comment: It looks as if your `Proxy` is not poly-kinded. Are you using the one from `Data.Proxy`? That one should work, I think.

Comment: Yes i’m using the one from Data.Proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` and use an explicit `forall`, otherwise you are not referring to the same `s`:

```
func :: forall s t . KnownSymbol s => MyType s t -> String
func _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

Comment: Ah the `forall`! I had given `ScopedTypeVariables` a go and it failed, so I worked around it like this, which seems to work: `func (_ :: MyType s t)  = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)`. Are the semantics equivalent?

Comment: @JorgeAdriano I think so.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by chi above is the proper way to do it. In any case, this arguably less elegant alternative without the `forall` should work too.

```
func :: KnownSymbol s => MyType s t -> String
func (_ :: MyType s t)  = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

I was forgetting it and worked around it like that. I think it's equivalent.

*never mind the answer below, it's way off...*

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

import Data.Proxy
data Symbol 
data MyType (s :: Symbol) t = MyType t

class KnownSymbol (s :: Symbol) where

symbolVal :: Proxy s -> String
symbolVal = undefined

func :: KnownSymbol s => MyType s t -> String
func _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

This type checks here. Perhaps it's your `class` definition not specifying kind?

Comment: I don’t understand your answer. I surely didn’t define KnownSymbol myself. And the signature of your symbolVal is not the same as that from GHC.TypeLits

Comment: I didn't know that. You didn't provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I was kind of winging it from what I had.

Comment: I’m sorry for that, but KnownSymbol is something really tied to GHC and type-level computation, it was clear I was not talking about a generic class called “KnownSymbol”, I think. It’s as if I had a problem with printf in a C program.

Comment: It's fine, doesn't matter. `KnownSymbol` was, well, unknown to me :) complete examples are just pretty useful though, note the how first question also asked whether you used your own proxy.  You could have some extension missing, etc

Comment: Regarding the solution by the way, I like chi's more with the `forall`. The way I used it here comes pretty handy when working with GADTs though (which is why I'm used to using it).